# data.table rolling join within range

Tags: r, data.table

Using R 3.2.2, data.table 1.9.5

Price data is available in intervals as shown below.  Please note that the ranges may not be contiguous as shown in records 3 and 4.

```
   id price    startdt      enddt
1: aa   259 2005-01-01 2005-06-30
2: aa   259 2005-07-01 2005-12-31
3: aa   249 2006-01-01 2006-06-30
4: aa   239 2007-01-01 2007-06-30
```

Sales data has the following format.

```
   id         dt sls
1: aa 2005-03-01 250
2: aa 2005-08-15 240
3: aa 2005-12-31 300
4: aa 2006-08-01 100
5: aa 2007-04-01 400
```

I would like to create the following table.

```
   id         dt sls price
1: aa 2005-03-01 250   259
2: aa 2005-08-15 240   259
3: aa 2005-12-31 300   259
4: aa 2006-08-01 100    NA   <== since there isn't a price in the price table for this date
5: aa 2007-04-01 400   239
```

Can somebody please show how to do this?  I am assuming that I will need to `melt` the price table so that dates are in 1 column and then do a rolling join with sales data.  The full table has 25million+ records for ~700k skus.

```
price.dt <- data.table(id=rep("aa",4),price=c(259,259,249,239),
    startdt=as.Date(c("2005-1-1","2005-7-1","2006-1-1","2007-1-1"),"%Y-%m-%d"),
    enddt=as.Date(c("2005-6-30","2005-12-31","2006-6-30","2007-6-30"),"%Y-%m-%d"))

sales.dt <- data.table(id=rep("aa",5),
    dt=as.Date(c("2005-3-1","2005-8-15","2005-12-31","2006-8-1","2007-4-1"),"%Y-%m-%d"),
    sls=c(250,240,300,100,400))

final.dt <- data.table(id=rep("aa",5),
    dt=as.Date(c("2005-3-1","2005-8-15","2005-12-31","2006-8-1","2007-4-1"),"%Y-%m-%d"),
    sls=c(250,240,300,100,400), price=c(259,259,259,NA,239))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
price.dt[sales.dt, on = c(id = 'id', startdt = 'dt'), roll = T
       ][enddt < startdt, price := NA][]
#   id price    startdt      enddt sls
#1: aa   259 2005-03-01 2005-06-30 250
#2: aa   259 2005-08-15 2005-12-31 240
#3: aa   259 2005-12-31 2005-12-31 300
#4: aa    NA 2006-08-01 2006-06-30 100
#5: aa   239 2007-04-01 2007-06-30 400
```

You can then remove extra columns, rename `startdt` and so on. Another option is using `foverlaps`.

Comment: thx.  if possible, can you please post the code for the `foverlaps` approach as well.  I am not seeing how to match the id, and the fact that one of the tables does not have a range.

Comment: @ironv you add another column in `price.dt` that identical to `dt` and then use those two columns for the overlap join. I'd recommend playing around on your own first before coming back to SO if that doesn't work out.

Comment: Got it.  I didn't realize the by.x and by.y.  id was included in each of them.  As of now, the by's do not allow repeating column names.  Hence, adding the tmp column like you suggested is required.  Thx again.