# Searching for Closest values in a Data Frame

Tags: r, search, dataframe

I have a question about searching and finding values from data frames in R. Let's say that I have a data frame with a whole bunch of different columns and that there is a section in the data frame such as:

```
Instrument |     Time     |   Microsecond
-------------------------------------------
   ....    |     ....     |     ....
-------------------------------------------
ABC        |   10:32:40   |     420
-------------------------------------------
ABC        |   10:32:40   |     422
-------------------------------------------
   ....    |     ....     |     ....
```

Now, let's also say for instance that I have values/strings given as:

Time: 10:32:40

Microsecond: 421

Basically, I was wondering whether there was a function or method in R (or in the `data.table` package) which would allow me to use the Time and Microsecond information to search the data frame such that it would find the closest 'lower' value (or value equal to) the Time and Microsecond values. For example, for the Time: 10:32:40 and Microsecond: 421 information I gave, the closest lower value in the data frame would be Time: 10:32:40 and Microsecond: 420.

In addition, I would like to find the closest 'upper' value (or value equal to) in a data frame, which (for the example data frame above) would be Time: 10:32:40 and Microsecond: 422.

Lastly, I would like to find the closest lower/upper value or (value equal to) the information I have. What I mean by "value equal to" is that if there were a row in the data frame which was exactly equal to the information I have (i.e. Time: 10:32:40 and Microsecond: 421) then I would like to use that instead of using the 'closest' values - to put it bluntly, if the row information in a data frame is exactly the same as the information I have then that has higher priority to me compared to the 'closest' values.

I should also note that I want to be able to find the closest values for the "Time" column in addition to the "Microsecond" column since I might have to round up/down the values in the "Time" column.

Is there a function or method which can do this? If what I said isn't clear then please let me know.

Comment: Take a search here on Stackoverflow for `data.table`s 'rolling join' or 'non-equi joins' - I think either may be useful for you. E.g. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634923/data-table-rolling-join-within-range

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out now!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to handle it is to keep only rows not duplicated

```
notDupes<- your_df[-duplicated(your_df),] 
arrange(notDupes,Time, Microsecond)
```

Then you will have all the associated times in ascending order, followed by microseconds in ascending order. Once it is in order, you can select the higher and lower closest times by simply taking three consecutive rows (testing first to see if any rows are duplicates).

```
dupes<- your_df[duplicated(your_df),]
```

It does not include the first instance of the duplicated row, but all the following duplicates of it are included.

If you wanted the whole list, you could reverse the order and run it a second time then subtract one from the other and add the difference to the first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! At present, the data frame is already in ascending order, and I originally used the method you mentioned (I used the which() function to find exact rows in the data frame which matched my information). The problem I'm having at the moment though is that for some information I have, there are no rows in the data frame that match it, so I'm trying to find a function or method capable of finding the closest values/strings in the data frame which match my information

Comment: If you sort by all of the fields you are looking at in the order of importance, time then microsecond, your next closest times should be right above and right below...

Comment: Unfortunately I have to keep all the rows, even if they look like they're duplicated. It's a bit of a weird problem, but it's due to the fact that the data frame doesn't contain 'all' the information and that there in fact should be a nanosecond column as well to make things completely accurate - if there was a nanosecond column then I wouldn't be having any problems :(

Comment: Without code and a dataset to play with, it is hard to get you where you need to be. Probably it will involve using for loops to identify the data you are looking to work with and tagging them in another column. You  might have to do it the hard way if the continuity of other columns matters.